# Unusual Ajax Response Behaviour - <style> and <tr> do not seem to like each other

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

## The Problem

`<tr>` and `<td>` tags are getting stripped off from the HTML that is returned when there is the usage of `<style>` tag.

## HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="first">
            <td>Abc</td>
            <td>abc@def.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add Row" />
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#add', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'abc.php',
            success: function (ret) {
                $('tr.first').after(ret);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

## abc.php (CASE 1)

```
<style type="text/css">
  .someclass{
     font-weight:bold;
  }
</style>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class="someclass">Something goes here</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

## abc.php (CASE 2)

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class="someclass">Something goes here</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

## What's happening?

In **CASE 1**, the end result is turning out to be

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="first">
            <td>Abc</td>
            <td>abc@def.com</td>
        </tr>
        <div class="someclass">Something goes here</div>
        <!-- where did tr and td go? -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In **CASE 2** (the expected output), the end result is

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="first">
            <td>Abc</td>
            <td>abc@def.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="someclass">Something goes here</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

- Is this a normal behaviour or did I come across some kind of a bug?
- If it's supposed to behave like that, what is the reason behind it?

Comment: what did console.log(ret) displays in the success call back..?

Comment: Thats because it's invalid syntax. a tbody can only contain a tr, that's it. Put your style tags outside of your table. If your HTML breaks the standards you can and will get unexpected results

Comment: @Liam So if I put the style tag inside a `<td>`, that should work too right? If you can put that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't put anything inside a `<tbody>` tag, but a `<tr>`, any other tag is invalid (this includes `<style>` and `<div>`)

[HTML 4.0 specification for tbody](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3)

> Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or
>   more table body sections, using the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements,
>   respectively. This division enables user agents to support scrolling
>   of table bodies independently of the table head and foot. When long
>   tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be
>   repeated on each page that contains table data.
>
> The table head and table foot should contain information about the
>   table's columns. **The table body should contain rows of table data.**
>
> When present, each THEAD, TFOOT, and TBODY contains a row group. Each
>   row group must contain at least one row, defined by the TR element.

Creating invalid markup will produce unexpected results. If in doubt check your markup at http://validator.w3.org/

You could (as you ask) put the style inside a `<td>`, this would be valid. I wouldn't suggest this though. A much better solution would be to put it near the top or bottom of your page or better yet inside an external .css file which you then reference.

Comment: Thanks. Will accept it as soon as the system allows me to. Lost 2 hours on it trying to figure out the reason behind it

Answer (score 1):

Where you are putting your `style` is causing invalid structure of markup, instead you can put it in the `head` or even you can put outside of `table` itself:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .someclass{
    font-weight:bold;
  }
</style>

<table>
   ...other stuff related to table
</table>
```